Error on Async/Await in ASP.NET .Net Framework 4.8 - The thread gets stuck and never callsback
As Pointed out by @Charlieface and Srinivasan Jayakumar. Creating a new thread to call the code solves the problem, i know it is not the best pratice,but best pratices and very old legacy applications don't comunicate very well. I could not find a way to debug System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext and find why this deadlocks here and not in the windows service. Anyways it is solved, thanks all
I have a very odd bug in ASP.NET .net framework 4.8. If i load a class by reflection, call a syncronous method that inside it calls an asyn method by using .Wait() or .GetAwaiter().GetResult(). If this method uses any await that don't have .ConfigureAwait(false) the aplication hangs, the await never returns and the IIS hangs (after a while it come backs to life, problably when the apppool recicles). PS: In this sample the IIS doen't hangs, it accept new requests, the calls just never return and the thread gets stuck, but in the original app it happens.
This only happens in ASP.NET .net Framework 4.8, the code is shared by a service written in .net framework 4.8 and another one written in .net 8 without any problem (the DLL have multi targets) .
I found some work arounds:
1 - If i change the page to Async and everything to async from top down i don't get the bug --> Not an option as it is a legacy monolith.

2 - Change every call inside the Method to .ConfigureAwait(false) -> Not an option too, much of the code is auto generated by some tools we developed (ORM mostly) and we don't plan to change becouse of this very specific problem.

3 - Turn the method to syncronous and remove all asyncronous calls -> this one we adopted, even if we don't like the solution it have very low impact as this is a very specific code.
I read a lot about it during this weekend and from what i could speculate it is probably some problem with a custom SyncronizationContext that ASP.NET uses and the callback get messed up, but as it hangs i can't really be sure and it is puzzling me.
EDIT for clarification: Whats i really want to know is how i can debug these kind of situations, and whats is really happening in this case. As the state machine is created by the compiler i really don't know how i can debug and see why the tread is just lost when it should resume
I Uploaded a sample i did to reproduce the error (Sample on GitHUB), just correct the path to the DLL and start the website and you will get the error.
The Call to the component.
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string Lstr_PathDLL = "full path to DLL";                   
     Assembly Lobj_Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Lstr_PathDLL);            
     IAwaitErrorNetFrameworkASPNET Lobj_Error = (IAwaitErrorNetFrameworkASPNET)Lobj_Assembly.CreateInstance("LoadedByReflection.AwaitErrorNetFrameworkASPNET");
     Lobj_Error.Test();
     
 }

the class in the component
using Dominio;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoadedByReflection
{
    public class AwaitErrorNetFrameworkASPNET : IAwaitErrorNetFrameworkASPNET
    {


        public void Test()
        {
            Teste2().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }



        private async Task Teste2()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}


don't call GetAwaiter().GetResult() that can deadlock like you are experiencing

@DanielA.White As stated in the post, this is an old legacy application, we can't really change it to put async from the beggining (at least not now), but the question is more to know whats is happening in this particular case (i don't think it is a dead lock, as the original thread is free to resume) and how i can debug a and investigate these kind of problems.

This sounds like a classic deadlock, much as you insist it isn't. ASP.Net classic has a synchronization context: unless you can put your own in place or launch another thread separate from the scheduler then you are at risk of deadlocks.

@Ryan yes it is a webforms application.

@Charlieface i don't insist on nothing lol, i really don't know what is happening, i actually opened the thread to find out. There is any way to debug it and make sure it is a deadlock?

@ÂngeloCossa, there is an idea to substitute ASP.Net classic synchronization context to a custom synchronization context, which uses threadpool under the hood. Classic, as far as i remember is single-threaded, ie thread which begins request handling, returns back for every continuation in that request handling, like in WinForms/WPF apps, that's why you get deadlock. The only thing to think about is to find a right place to substitute. Otherwise, don't use GetAwaiter().GetResult() in your code, as aforementioned above.

@Ryan actually we choose to not use async at all in these case for internal reasons, what i am trying here is to learn how to debug and inspect these kind of situations.

@Charlieface doing it on another thread actually solves the problem, but i am still curious, how can i trace or debug these kind of situations, any help would be welcome :)

I think the call to Teste2().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); is creating issue in your code. By using this the current thread will wait for return value from the function called. This runs on the same thread that call the page_load. As the Teste2() is void function and does not return any return value the mail thread keeps waiting for the return value from Teste2() forever. To avoid this deadlock you need to run the Teste2() in a a separate thread using Task class. I modified your Githib code and found this working.
Kindly replace with the code below,
namespace LoadedByReflection
{
    public class AwaitErrorNetFrameworkASPNET : IAwaitErrorNetFrameworkASPNET
    {


        public void Test()
        {
            //Teste2().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Task callTask = Task.Run(() => Teste2());
            callTask.Wait();
        }



        private async Task Teste2()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}

Regarding the debug, I put break-point in Teste2().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); to understand the deadlock that blocks the main thread.

There are some coments on this:
yes, creating a new thread works fine @Charlieface pointed it out in a reply. Thats a very good solution that i will probably use, thanks

As for the debug, this code works fine on a windons service, no problem at all, it only deadlocks in ASP.NET. So probably something to do with the System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.

i tryied to decompile to see if i could debug and find the problem, but it did not entered the decompiled code. Next i tryed to copy the entire code of  System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext to my project so i could set it as the SynchronizationContext of the thread and debug, but it references a lot of internal classes that i would have to bring to the project too and as it was late in the night i just stopped. i Will try another time. Any sugestion on show to debug and find why it locks here and not in the service would be apreciated.
